# Can someone calculate the time complexity in big Oh notation

Tags: python, big-o

Can someone help me explain the big Oh complexity of this algorithm? I've been trying for an hour, but I don't understand the complexity of the recursion. I know the 3 first statements are O(1) and thought that the ones underneath that were O(n/2) and O(n/2) so together O(n), but I am not sure.

```
def sum(a):
    if len ( a ) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len ( a ) == 1:
        return a [0]
    m = len (a )//2

    b = sum (a [: m ])
    c = sum (a [ m :])

    return b + c
```

Comment: what does this algo do? What is `a` here?

Comment: Redefining the builtin sum might confuse some here

Comment: Maybe your teacher threw this at you as a trick question.  It presents itself using a binary search-style recursion, but really you just end up touching every element once.  You sort of need to do this to get a total count of the string.  So, it's still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the number of times you call recursively the function, this number is `2n-1`. For each call, you have a constant number of constant time operations (so `O(1)`).

To conclude the time complexity is `O(n)`, linear to the length of the list.

You may try to define a recurrence relation in order to prove it formally.

**Note**
The question may be tricky, due to the slicing operation used at each iteration. This depends on the implementation details (for python it looks like it is `O(k)` with `k` the length of the list but for numpy it should be `O(1)` as pointed out in the comments) and may be easily replaced by passing indexes (e.g., start, end) and not a sliced list.
*Here I assume the operation takes constant time*.

Comment: The creation of the sublists is an implicit loop.

Comment: Experimenttally, `In [4]: %timeit sum(range(1000)) ፨
1.72 ms ± 62.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
 ፨ 
In [5]: %timeit sum(range(10000)) ፨ 
17.1 ms ± 50 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
 ፨ 
In [6]: %timeit sum(range(100000))  ፨
169 ms ± 522 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: as @tobias_k says in comment, statistics of `a` really matters.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Right, those have O(n/2), too, so 4x O(n/2), but asymptotically it's still O(n) -- assuming that `len` is O(1).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Python's time complexity documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), slicing a list is `O(k)` where `k` is the length of the slice.

The function calls itself recursively on the two slices, each with size `n / 2` (ignoring off-by-one due to integer rounding). The recurrence relation is thus:

`T(n) = 2 T(n / 2) + O(n)`

... where `O(n)` comes from the two slicing operations `a[:m]` and `a[m:]`.

> According to the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), this is **`O(n log n)`**.

---

To make the algorithm `O(n)` as it should be, one could pass sub-array indices instead of directly slicing the array, or use `numpy`'s array type.

Comment: if `a` is, for example, `numpy` array. slicing is `O(1)`, no code change requierd.

Comment: @appleapple good point; although OP did not include a `numpy` tag